# Repeat the same fields in a form

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms, symfony-2.1

What is the best way of repeating the same form fields within a form?

---

I'd like the user to submit multiple `Name / Phone number` rows.

```
class contactType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name1', 'text')
            ->add('phone1', 'text');

            ->add('name2', 'text')
            ->add('phone2', 'text');

            ->add('name3', 'text')
            ->add('phone3', 'text');

            ....etc
    }
}
```

Ideally, I would like the user to enter as many fields as he wants...

1- Is there a way to avoid repeating the code here?

2- How should I store these name/phone in the underlying object?

3- Can I store it as an array, but still apply some validation rules?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using:

```
$builder->add('phones', 'collection', array('type' => new PhoneType()));
```

And `'allow_add' => true` in your Form Builder.

Take a look at the [How to Embed a Collection of Forms](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html) Cookbook page.

Comment: I think you're right @Juan. Do you think there is way to do a collection of `name + phone`?

Comment: Yea, you should add a name field in your PhoneType class aswell.