# twig form multiple block in symfony4

Tags: symfony, input, twig

I have a form with block of the different input field.

When I use, standard twig function I get one block:

```
{{ form(form) }}
```

If I want to change something inside form I use, for example:

```
{{ form_start(form) }}
  {{ form_widget(form.firstName) }}
  {{ form_widget(form.lastName) }}
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

And everything is fine with this, but here I use JS for adding multiple block of the same field in the form (like can be possible to add multiple person in one form). When I want to edit data, I catch all data from the DB, of course, and want to show blocks in the twig.

```
{{ form_start(form) }}
  {# somehow start loop data from the DB here #}
    <div class='block'>
      {{ form_widget(form.firstName) }}
      {{ form_widget(form.lastName) }}
    </div>
  {# somehow end loop data from the DB here #}
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

Is it possible in the Twig, or I should use old school here?

Comment: Did you read the twig docs? https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/for.html

Comment: Did you read my question? It is not loop for show data. It is loop for editing, for multiple edit fields (array fields).

Comment: Yes, and what is wrong in using `{% for user in users_in_data_from_db %} ... {% endfor %}`?

Comment: Wrong is in multiple fields. Twig cannot in this way create multiple input text field for firstName. This is now way. But, I ask what is the trick in this case, what I have?

Comment: This is nice example if you want to make multiple one field: https://symfony-collection.fuz.org/symfony3/form-with-several-collections, but if you want to make multiple block of fields, I do not know how to do it.

Comment: Is that what you want - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13132338/repeat-the-same-fields-in-a-form?

Comment: i'm sorry I was reading your question but I don't seem to get ahold of what you want. is it, by chance, looping through all fields in the form and displaying each property `<div class='block'>{{ form_widget(form.X) }}</div>`, using a for loop instead of manually?

Answer (score 0):

For all who google for same question, answer is here:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_collections.html